# angular 6 adding new data to table not working after applying search filter through pipe in html

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a web application in Angular 6. In ts file i have a data table with hard coded data. i have applied a search filter through pipe. filter is working fine but the new entry button is not. Whenever i click on new entry it doesnt show the new field automatically. it does only after i type something in search box and then delete it.

Search pipe

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
    if (!filter) {
      return items;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
      return items;
    }

    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      const filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

      if (defaultFilter) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] === '', true));
      } else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] === '';
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's because to work as you expect it to work, your pipe would need to be impure. You shouldn't use a pipe to filter an array, as explained in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Thanks thats sorted

Comment: You should read the documentation I linked to, understand why using a pipe is a bad idea, and instead use what the documentation recommends using as a replacement: *The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself. The component can expose a filteredHeroes or sortedHeroes property and take control over when and how often to execute the supporting logic. Any capabilities that you would have put in a pipe and shared across the app can be written in a filtering/sorting service and injected into the component.*